CentOS7 環境で glibc を 2.27 にアップデートすると、どんな影響がありますか？
質問
CentOS7 環境で glibc を 2.27 にアップデートすると、どんな影響がありますか？
起動しなくなる可能性もありますか？
やりたいこと
CentOS7 で Puppeteer を使用したい
調べたこと
→ Puppeteer を使用するためには、Node.js 18以上が必要
→ Node.js 18 をインストールするためには、glibc 2.27 以上が必要
NodeJS 18 revert to building on CentOS 7, RHEL 7, Ubuntu Bionic 18.04, other other LTS distros #43246

どのようにアップデートするのでしょうか？ アップデート方法によっても影響の仕方が変わってくると思います。

是非はともかく似たようなことをしている記事がこれらでしょう。DropboxをCentOS 7で動かす, CentOS7でDropBox glibc2.9以上でないと使えなくなった対応, glibc アップデート方法 まとめ, patchelfを使って動的ライブラリ(libcとか)を変える, safely upgrade glibc on CentOS 7

題意に反するかもしれませんが
https://blog.centos.org/2023/04/end-dates-are-coming-for-centos-stream-8-and-centos-linux-7/
CentOS7 は 2024/June/30 の時点で既に EOL です。もうすでにサポートはありません。現実的解は新しいバージョンなり他のディストリビューションなりに乗り換えることです。
https://www.centos.org/download/ によると CentOS9 が最新な様子。 EOL 2027-05-31
なにがなんでもどうしても CentOS7 を使い続けなければならない理由がありますか？

と言いたいところなんですが CentOS ってもう開発終了なんですよね。 CentOS の開発者の一部は、ほぼ同名だけど違うプロジェクトである CentOS Stream ってのに移行しているって状況です。んでどちらも CentOS 8（サポート切れ） とか CentOS 9 とか出しているあたりが訳ワカランという。その辺の面倒に巻き込まれたくなかったら別のディストロにしたほうが良いかも。
ということでディストロお引越しするなら何が良いか？　なんて質問があったら別途挙げていただくと、オイラを含め読者いろいろに役立つかもしれないし、買い物リスト質問はクローズ対象になるかもしれないし、って難しい状況です。

そんなに古くなっている認識がなかったので、回答を読んで検索してみてびっくりしました。CentOS9へ変更します。

「ほぼ同名だけど違うプロジェクトである CentOS Stream」。え……。これまでもそしてこれからも「CentOS」が一番標準的なOSなのかと思っていました。

glibc は OS の根幹に関わるパッケージなので、おいそれと簡単にアップデートすることはできません。
システムの標準とは別ディレクトリにインストールする方法もありますが、システムに影響を与える可能性があります。
774RR さんの回答にもある通り、CentOS7 は既に EOL なので、OS 自体を新しいものに更新する方が現実的かと思いますが、代替案としては Puppeteer の古いバージョンを試してみる、Docker コンテナ内で Puppeteer を動かしてみる、辺りを検討してみてください。
https://pptr.dev/guides/docker

Puppeteer offers a Docker image that includes Chrome for Testing along with the required dependencies and a pre-installed Puppeteer version. The image is available via the GitHub Container Registry.


例えば, Linuxシステムを最新の状態にすべく, カーネル(だけ)を最新版に置き換える。
構造・仕組みを知らないとそのような行動を起こすかも知れません
カーネルだけを変更や, libcだけを変更は, 同じくらい危険です
GNU Cライブラリー(glibc)は libcの一種。
(C言語ベースの) OSに付属の libcは, 一般的にはメーカーが提供するものだが, Linuxディストリビューションでは GNU の libcがよく使われている。
Linux の man pages によると(Linuxに限らないが)
以下のように記されています。

2 システムコール
カーネルが処理しなければならない関数。
3 ライブラリコール
libc の関数の大部分。

libcは (2)と (3)がほとんどすべてのはずで, (2) はカーネルのシステムコールを C言語から呼び出すことができるようにする, いわばラッパーです
このため, カーネルに対応した libcが必要で,
また libcに対応したカーネルでないと, 誤動作を起こす危険性があります
カーネル, libc, (そして起動に伴う initramfs) それらが変更になるということは
システムにもアプリにも多大な影響を与えます。動かなくなるとか誤動作するとか。

Puppeteer を利用するのが目的であれば Homebrew (が管理しているNode.js)を利用することで実現できます。
Homebrewは自身のエコシステムを持っていてglibcも自前で管理しています(のでシステムのglibcを更新する必要はありません)。
node@18, puppeteer-core, CentOS7のchromium-browser で動作しました。

ただし最新バージョンのGoogle Chromeでテストしたい、といった場合にはこの方法では駄目です。(Homebrewが管理していないアプリケーションであるところの)Google Chromeが新しいglibcを要求すると思われるため。
